# How can I generate a sequence of numbers in orleans without using external providers?

Tags: orleans

I'd like to have a similar behavior that Postgres sequences have in a grain itself. So I can give a unique number to each incoming request without going to a DB.

I can use a DB sequence but then my API will be depend on a DB connection.

Is it a good task for Orleans or it's better to ask a DB for the number?

Comment: Do you want to assign sequential number across entire cluster?

Comment: Yes, that was the main idea.

Comment: The best thing you can do here is to measure and compare both approaches for different loads, like 10 parallel requests, 100, 1000, 10,000 etc. Also do a research about how it is implemented in the databse. There must be some lock there. But still - you need to benchmark.